# Improving workflow with Dopesheet-Editor

Tags: animation, workflow, dopesheet

I am working on a lenghty animation with lots of small, consecutive animations. currently all in one scene und very unstructured over the dopesheet-editor. I would like to group-up the single animations, involving several objects each, since it got really messy really fast. Changing things afterwards is prone to errors like that. What are your recommendations? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You mean like the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/nla/introduction.html)?